# Magento 2 > Partial search on model name

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, autocomplete

How can I have the default catalog search mechanism search on part of an attribute (in my case - the model attribute)? As it seems out of the box - the search works only on full word, or the beginning of the word - but, if the user enters a middle part of the word - it doesn't find the product

e.g. I have a product named "Samsung Galaxy S7" and the model attribute is "SM-G930F" - I want the search query "G930" to find the product

The weird thing is that in the admin control panel search - it does find it

I understand that the solution has something to do with `search_request.xml` but I can't find information about this specific case

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Native magento uses mysql fulltext search with full match. It build query in file `src/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/Query/Builder/Match.php` (`$matchQuery =`  ...)